# Spotfire: "limit data using markings" by python script

Tags: python, spotfire

Is there a way to check or uncheck certain markings in "limit data using markings" in a visualization through a python script?

Comment: This is interesting. May I ask why you would want to do this? Usually removing a limit data using markings, unless it is the last / bottom marking in your data flow, would likely skew the results. I'm just wondering if there may be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from https://community.tibco.com/questions/limit-data-using-markings-python-script

```
from Spotfire.Dxp import Data
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Add(Document.Data.Markings["Marking"])
```

They "hide" the Markings in the Filters.