# Set the marking on a viz through IPython

Tags: spotfire

Similar to this question but not quite the same: [Spotfire: "limit data using markings" by python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224691/spotfire-limit-data-using-markings-by-python-script)

I have a script that currently looks like this:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp import Data
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

#Remove the current Marking Filter
for filtering in vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings:
    vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Remove(filtering)

#Set the new Marking Filter
vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Add(Document.Data.Markings["Marking (4)"])

#Set the new Marking
#Need code here
```

I need to set a new marking for the visualization so that I can then use that for another visualization. Specifically, I need to set this box:[image]

**UPDATE**
I am able to set markings using this piece of code:

```
vc = vis.As[VisualContent]()
marking = vc.Data.MarkingReference
marking.SetSelection(marking.GetSelection(dataTable),dataTable)
```

This does mark the records I want, but because it does not change the setting in the Marking box, it will not let me drill down further (filtered to the same marking it is setting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script ultimately worked for me:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp import Data
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import *

if Document.Properties['KPIHierLevel'] == '<[SBA_NAME] NEST [MARKET_NAME]>':
    Document.Properties['KPIHierLevel'] = '<[MARKET_NAME] NEST [BRAND]>'
    for filtering in vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings:
        vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Remove(filtering)
    vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Add(Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference)
    vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.MarkingReference = (Document.Data.Markings["Marking (7)"])
elif Document.Properties['KPIHierLevel'] == '<[MARKET_NAME] NEST [BRAND]>':
    Document.Properties['KPIHierLevel'] = '<[BRAND] NEST [PRODUCT]>'
    for filtering in vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings:
        vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Remove(filtering)
    vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.Filterings.Add(Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference)
    vis.As[VisualContent]().Data.MarkingReference = (Document.ActiveMarkingSelectionReference)
```

I also created a Reset script that is similar to this but sets the marking back to something other than Marking (7).